# jquery- On onchange event tab content is not getting displayed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Below is my **HTML code:**

```
<select id="sourceNameDropdownId" label="condition " style="width:300px;">
</select>
<div id="tabs" class="selector">
</div>
```

Here, is my **javascript code:**

```
 $("#DropdownId").change(function () {
     var sid= $("#DropdownId option:selected").text();
     afterclick(sid);
 });
```

I am calling an onchange event on dropdown list, and the selected value i am passing to function **afterclick**

```
function afterclick(sid){
          var tabsContainer = document.getElementById("tabs");
          var crawlTab=document.createElement("ul");

         //here in my actual code i am making a ajax call to fetch values for crawlList, providing static values here

          var crawlList=["name1","name2","name3","name4"];

          $.each(crawlList, function( index, crawlType ) {

                var crawlTabElement=document.createElement("li");
                crawlTabElement.innerHTML= '<a href="' +"#"+crawlType + '">' +crawlType+'</a>';
                crawlTab.appendChild(crawlTabElement);

          });

          tabsContainer.appendChild(crawlTab);
          var count=1;var tabCount=1;

          $.each(crawlList, function( index, crawlType ) {
              var contentCrawlTab=document.createElement("div");
              contentCrawlTab.setAttribute("id",crawlType);
              var p='<p>'+crawlType+'</p>';

              contentCrawlTab.innerHTML=p;
              tabsContainer.appendChild(contentCrawlTab);

          });
          $( ".selector" ).tabs();

  }
```

This code is working fine when for the first time page gets loaded and a value is selected from the dropdown, but when i re-select value from the dropdown tabs are not getting displayed properly.
This is when i select value for the first time after page is loaded.
[image]

And when i reselect the value from dropdown its showing like this-

[image]

Is there something like **reload** to reload the **tabs** div entirely, as it seems that its appending the previous values and next time when **afterclick** function is called tab elements are not getting displayed properly. 
I tried clearing the "tabs" div too, using **$( "#tabs " ).empty()**But it didn't worked for me.

Please help me out.

Comment: Shouldn't `#DropdownId` be `sourceNameDropdownId` ?

Comment: what happened when you used tabs.empty and where did you put it?

Comment: Please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working code.

```js
$().ready(function () {
        $(".selector").tabs();
        $("#DropdownId").change(function () {
            var sid = $("#DropdownId option:selected").text();
            afterclick(sid);
        });
    });
    function afterclick(sid) {
        var tabsContainer = document.getElementById("tabs");
        tabsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        var crawlTab = document.createElement("ul");

        //here in my actual code i am making a ajax call to fetch values for crawlList, providing static values here

        var crawlList = [sid + "1", sid + "2", sid + "3", sid + "4"];

        $.each(crawlList, function (index, crawlType) {
            if (crawlType != null) {
                var crawlTabElement = document.createElement("li");
                crawlTabElement.innerHTML = '<a href="' + "#" + crawlType + '">' + crawlType + '</a>';
                crawlTab.appendChild(crawlTabElement);
            }
        });

        tabsContainer.appendChild(crawlTab);
        var count = 1; var tabCount = 1;

        $.each(crawlList, function (index, crawlType) {
            if (crawlType != null) {
                var contentCrawlTab = document.createElement("div");
                contentCrawlTab.setAttribute("id", crawlType);
                var p = '<p>' + crawlType + '</p>';

                contentCrawlTab.innerHTML = p;
                tabsContainer.appendChild(contentCrawlTab);
            }

        });
        $(".selector").tabs('destroy');
        $(".selector").tabs();

    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select id="DropdownId" label="condition " style="width:300px;">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">--Select--</option>
    <option>Bilna-ID</option>
    <option>IndiatimesShopping</option>
</select>
<div id="tabs" class="selector">
</div>
```